# mask 0 values during normalization

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing normalization for datasets but the data contains a lot of 0 because of padding.

I can mask them during model training but apparently, these zero will be affected when I applied normalization.

`from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,MinMaxScaler`

I am currently using the Sklearn library to do the normalization

For example, given a 3D array with dimension (4,3,5) as (batch, step, features)

The number of zero-padding varied from batch to batch as these are the features I extracted from audio files, that have varying lengths, using a fixed window size.

```
[[[0 0 0 0 0],
  [0 0 0 0 0],
  [0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[1 2 3 4 5],
  [4 5 6 7 8],
  [9 10 11 12 13]],

 [[14 15 16 17 18],
  [0 0 0 0 0],
  [24 25 26 27 28]],

 [[0 0 0 0 0],
  [423 2 230 60 70],
  [0 0 0 0 0]]
]
```

I wish to perform normalization by column so

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1,X_train.shape[-1])).reshape(X_train.shape)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test.reshape(-1,X_test.shape[-1])).reshape(X_test.shape)
```

However, in this case, zeros are treated as effective values. For example, the minimum value of the first column should be 1 instead of 0.

Further, the 0's values are also changed after applying the scalers but I wish to keep them as 0's so I can mask them during training. `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))`

Is there any way to mask them during normalization so only the 2nd step and 3rd step in this example are used in normalization?

In addition, The actual dimension of the array for my project is bigger as (2000,50,68)
among the 68 features, the difference in values of the 68 features can be very large. I tried to normalize them by dividing each element by the biggest element in their row to avoid the impact from 0's but this did not work out well.

---

Comment: Did you try any ways? You should write your trial code here.

Comment: I could not find any way online

Comment: Show us the exact sequence of code where these zero-values are transformed to something you don't want.

Comment: Please [reprex] with input data and expected output

Comment: You should try something before asking here. Of course, if you can't implement, you may ask here. And you should write sample of data for process, These're the manner of StackOverflow

Comment: Thank you for the reminder and i have changed it

Comment: @Leo Are these samples in dataset padded same way (same amount of zeros before and after)? Or different samples padded differently, e.g. one sample has padding 3 zeros before and 5 after, another one has 7 zeros before and 4 after? Also if padding varies then maybe total amount of zeros in each sample is same or can be different too?

Comment: @Arty The number of padding changes between the batches. Some may have 10 paddings and some may have 20,etc

Comment: @Leo How are paddings organized? You said you have `(batch, step, features)` shape of data. So where are these zeros inserted? Into which of these 3 dimensions? E.g. in last dimension, features, can it have zeros inside, or features always either all zeros or all non-zeros? In your example you have `14 15 16 17 18` features, can you have sometimes `0 15 16 17 0` i.e. zeros left and right? Or you always have either all zeros `0 0 0 0 0` or all non-zeros `14 15 16 17 18`?

Comment: @Leo In your example I see that you have zeros only inserted into `batch` dimension. Meaning that you have either 2D array `(step, features)` of all zeros or all non-zeros. Is it always the case that these 2D arrays are either all zeros or all non-zeros?

Comment: @Arty Image in such way. There are 2000 audio files which make up the value of 1st dimension of the array. Each audio files has been analyzed for 50 times(steps) which made up the 2nd dimension. There are 136 different features from each analysis of the 50, made up the 3rd dimension, For all the steps, it is either 136 non-zero values or 136 zeros.

Comment: @Leo If you have whole 2D array of zeros then you can do preprocessing like in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64605021/941531)

Comment: @Leo If not, then I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @Leo Thanks for updating your examples! I'll delete my answer for now as it is not what you want.

Comment: @Arty Thank you for your time. And sorry for my terrible mistake. Basically, we cannot remove the 0's that way because it will distort the shape of the 2 dimension

Comment: @Leo Can you mention all operations that you need masking for? Two you mentioned - MinMaxScaler() and probably LSTM() in keras or some other kind of mask-supporting layer. Anything else? Because probably each of this operations/layers need different way of solving masking task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223862/discussion-between-arty-and-leo).

Comment: Also you may want to remove inside your queston block of text after `Update, something is wrong` because 1) it was just solved 2) to make question shorter and nicer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task of just [MinMaxScaler()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) masking can be solved by next code.

Each other operation needs separate way of handling, if you'll mention all operations that need masking then we can solve them one-by-one basis and I'll extend my answer. E.g. keras layers can be masked by [tf.keras.layers.Masking()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Masking) layer as you mentioned.

Next code min/max-scales only non zero features, the rest remain zeros.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

X = np.array([
     [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

     [[1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
      [4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
      [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]],

     [[14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [24, 25, 26, 27, 28]],

     [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [423, 2, 230, 60, 70],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
], dtype = np.float64)

nz = np.any(X, -1)
X[nz] = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X[nz])

print(X)
```

Output:

```
[[[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]]

 [[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.007109   0.13043478 0.01321586 0.05357143 0.04615385]
  [0.01895735 0.34782609 0.03524229 0.14285714 0.12307692]]

 [[0.03080569 0.56521739 0.05726872 0.23214286 0.2       ]
  [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.05450237 1.         0.10132159 0.41071429 0.35384615]]

 [[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
  [1.         0.         1.         1.         1.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]]]
```

If you need to train `MinMaxScaler()` on one dataset and apply it later on others then you can do next:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(X[np.any(X, -1)])
X[np.any(X, -1)] = scaler.transform(X[np.any(X, -1)])
Y[np.any(Y, -1)] = scaler.transform(Y[np.any(Y, -1)])
```

Comment: Yes, I tried your second part with fit and transform separately but the result is incorrect somehow. Would you mind take a look?

Comment: I have updated my question with the codes and output.

Comment: @Leo The reason that your code is not working is because you apply two times normalization to same array `X` inside function, to solve this add in the beginning of `masked_normalization()` function body next line `X, Y = np.copy(X), np.copy(Y)`. Also instead of computing `np.any(...)` several times for same array you may store result of `np.any(...)` into a variable and re-use it.

Comment: @Leo Also lets continue discussion inside [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223862/discussion-between-arty-and-leo) because comments are usually not for discussions.

Comment: @Leo Thanks for +50 points (bounty) for my answer! :)